# Is "Buy Now" button effective for product listing on mobile ecommerce?

Tags: usability, mobile, conversion, product

I know there are similar questions regarding effectiveness of "Add to cart" button on product listing. But their context is for desktop web design.

What I'm asking is specifically for **mobile** interface which has no hover gesture on cards/lists, therefore the "Buy Now" button always shown on each card. The button also direct you to checkout instead of just putting it on shopping cart. So the button serve a purpose for user who just want to buy single product in quick steps.

So, anyone did a research for this? I would like to know if it actually increase conversion or there are any better alternatives.

Comment: The answer is that it depends on your context and user demographic. For different context and users different things work better. So you should check for your context and users which one will trigger more sales.

Comment: Why do you say add to cart on the product list is only suitable for desktop? The flow is the same, therefore it should still be applicable in any case.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov yeah I think so too, this solution need to be tested first

Comment: @Majo0od my concern is that mobile has no hover state to reveal this "buy now" button. The case for desktop is when you want to make your UI less cluttered, you can just show the button when hovering on the product. So then mobile version would have buttons all over the product the user's looking

Comment: Just read my answer. I've added an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a buy now button on the product list is potentially significantly worse than an add to cart because you're taking them to checkout immediately where the purpose is to get them to get them through the funnel fast. I anticipate people abandoning if they go through the list page to checkout because they won't know what they are buying:

You should not add those buttons because of many reasons:

1. Customer needs to understand what this product really is before commitment.
2. What if they want more than one? Are you going to clutter the page with a quantity field too?
3. What if they want a different option(s), going to add that to the page as well?

Be careful with breaking conventions because they are *normally* placed there for a reason.

---

**EDIT**

I wanted to emphasize why you should stay away from buttons being present on the list page:

**Flow will be the same**: users will still find themselves going to the product page for more information and other utilities to potentially enhance their buying experience (whether adding more, changing style/colors, etc).

The only time you will ever show a button is if the user has already purchased this product, become familiar with it and just wants to re-buy it. In that case, a button could potentially be viable. Whether it is hidden or not (and hover reveals it) is irrelevant, users will still want to go to the product page for more information before purchasing.

Comment: I see. I wonder if this solution might turn off new users from coming back since it will only work for old users who understand/already bought the products.

What if A/B test were applied and the result show increase in conversion by, let's say 30% to 40% by confidence rate of more than 90%. Should we, as designers, stick to conventions that might have been long existed and proven effective until now and defend it or agree with result data that support such a problematic solution based on your answer?

Comment: I'd put a lot of weight on data versus sticking with conventions.  Life moves.  However if you are going to go with the data, make sure it is robust !

Comment: I'm not saying don't ever break conventions, but if you do, do it with good reason

Comment: @PhillipW sure thing, should confirm first whether the data is biased or not